# Is there a "Maximum connections vs hardware needed" chart for IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

As I'm looking at IIS 8 and Windows Server 2012, it says that virtually, there is no limit to handle simultaneous connection requests, and that it pretty much depends on the hardware you have.
My question is, is there some sort of table to determine something like "How much RAM/Processor" do I need to handle 300000 connections?

I'm pretty new at this stuff so all help is greatly appreciated. Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't a hard limit with this kind of stuff.  It really depends on the software / hardware running on the machine.  If you are just accepting TCP connections and not doing anything with them, you will be able to handle alot.  However, if you are also running a database server on that machine, you are going to be using CPU cycles for the database and be able to handle less connections.

Comment: Yup, my thoughts exactly but I was hoping that someone out here would have some way to determine the hardware needed, you know, like a formula or something

Comment: @JorgeCupi You kinda get a feel for it after doing it for awhile.